# Can't get my footer to go to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a footer on page and then I want to place a few divs above it but for some reason the footer seems to come up beside this divs instead of below it

I want the main footer to be above the footer

here is my code

```html
<div id ="mainfooter">

<div id = "links">

<h2>Quick Links</h2>

</div>

<div id ="sunday">

<h2>Join us this Sunday</h2>

<p>11am &amp; 6:30pm</p>

</div>

<div id="findus">

 <h2>Find Us</h2>

 

</div>
</div>


<div id="footer">

<p id="copyright"> &copy; <span id="copyright_span"></span> Elim Church</p>


</div>
```

here is my css

```css
 #links
{
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #000;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}

#sunday{
    padding-left: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    color: #000;
    float: left;
}


#findus{
    padding-left: 100px;
    color: #000;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

#mainfooter
{
    padding-top: 50px;
}


#footer {
    
   padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left:100px;
   background:#F3EFE0;    
 
    padding-bottom:40px;
    }
```

Comment: you can also use `footer` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `clear` after floated elements, add `clear: both` to `#footer`.

```
#footer {clear: both;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u0krtdjo/